# Rails: How to look for project time expiration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project which has set `end` (`datetime`). After this time is reached I want to disable some buttons on a project page and show it is finished.
My idea is to add a boolean flag `finished` and change it when `end` reaches `time.now`.

The question is, is there any better way than run a cron job each minute and watch for projects `end` datetime, compare it with actual time and when it is over, change the flag?
I am not sure if running cron job each minute is the most efficient way how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just a matter of displaying or not some buttons, this could be done at UI level and you could update your records once a day with a cron job, without running it every minute.

Another approach could be update the records just when an user asks for them. Like:

- User requested the specific project
- You fetch the project
- Before serving the project information you check the end time and updates the record
- Your program then serves the freshly update record

But, then again, this depends on the requirements.

And finally, you may join these two ideas. You may have a once|twice a day cron job to update records and also check and update things 'on the fly' as I suggested above.

Maybe you could post some more info to receive a more specific answer.

Comment: If you need any help, just let me know, ok?